# Submit Redux Form from the Parent Component - Remote Submit

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Probably I've checked all the docs and questions out there about this problem but I still couldn't fix it since long time. So, I decided to ask here.

As the title says I am trying to submit a redux form from its parent component. I tried adding hidden submit input, into the form and that works although this isn't the redux form way. What should I do?

Thanks for your help.

WorkExperienceForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Field, reduxForm } from 'redux-form';

import { renderHorizontalTextField } from '../Fields/TextFields';
import { renderTextAreaFieldWithLabelAndPopover } from '../Fields/TextAreaFields';

const WorkExperienceForm = ({ handleSubmit, onSubmit, shouldHide, form }) => {
    if(shouldHide) return false;    
    return(
        <form onSubmit={ handleSubmit(onSubmit) } className="form-horizontal">
            <Field name="companyName"
                type="text"
                label="Company Name"
                placeholder="Apple inc."
                id="input-company-name"
                component={renderHorizontalTextField} />

            <Field name="title"
                type="text"
                label="Title"
                placeholder="Marketing Specialist"
                id="input-title"
                component={renderHorizontalTextField} />

            <Field name="startYear"
                type="text"
                label="Start Year"
                placeholder=""
                id="input-start-year"
                component={renderHorizontalTextField} />

            <Field name="endYear"
                type="text"
                label="End Year"
                placeholder="Blank if current"
                id="input-end-year"
                component={renderHorizontalTextField} />

            <Field name="summary"
                rows="4"
                label="Summary"
                placeholder="Summary..."
                id="input-summary"
                component={renderTextAreaFieldWithLabelAndPopover} />
        </form>
    )
}

export default reduxForm({
    enableReinitialize: true
})(WorkExperienceForm);
```

This is the parent component

```
onSubmit(values){        
    this.props.createWorkExperience(values, () => {
        this.props.notify();
    })
}

render(){
    if(!this.props.candidate || !this.props.candidate['workExperience'].length > 0) return this.renderEmptyState();
    const activeClass = this.state.displayForm ? 'btn btn-success btn-block mt8' : 'btn btn-primary btn-block mt8'

    return(
        <div>
            { this.renderWorkExperience() }
            <WorkExperienceForm {...this.props} 
                form='postWorkExperienceForm' 
                onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
                shouldHide={!this.state.displayForm} />

            <button type={ this.state.displayForm ? 'submit' : 'button' }
                htmlFor='postWorkExperienceForm'
                className={activeClass} >{ this.state.displayForm ? 'Save' : 'Add Work Experience' }
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Can you make a CodeSandbox example and I'll take a look?

Comment: Also, why are you trying to do it this way?

Comment: @Colin what way?

Comment: Why are you trying to submit a form from the parent?

Comment: Because of the design of the app. I need this form to be imported in 3 different places and the same form is used for both editing and creating.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the documentation is sparse regarding this matter.

I think you may have `Context` issues.  I think you should move the button to the Form Component and pass the `mySubmit` (renamed it from `onSubmit` for clarity) function to the Form Component with an arrow function via `onSubmit` property.

```
mySubmit(formValues){        
    this.props.createWorkExperience(formValues, () => {
        this.props.notify();
    })
}

<WorkExperienceForm {...this.props} 
      form='postWorkExperienceForm' 
      onSubmit={(formValues) => this.mySubmit(formValues)}
      shouldHide={!this.state.displayForm} />
```

Then in the Form Component wrap the `onSubmit` in the `handleSubmit` function.

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
```

Here is a example where we recently had to do this with `Redux-Form`.
Maybe, it will help you some.

> Note, we are using `FLOW`.

Parent Component: [beer.add.component.js](https://github.com/TransEmpiric/iso-web-template/blob/master/src/main/trans-react/client/src/components/beer/beer.add.component.js)

Form Component: [beer.add.form.component.js](https://github.com/TransEmpiric/iso-web-template/blob/master/src/main/trans-react/client/src/components/form/beer.add.form.component.js)

> [Live production](https://isowebtemplate.transempiric.com/signIn) example, so you know that it works. 
>   Note, The SignInForm uses the same pattern.

Comment: I had to keep the button outside because of the ui design but I changed the ui a bit and ended up placing the button into the form component. This way everything works. Also I didn't need this. `onSubmit={(formValues) => this.mySubmit(formValues)}`. This was enough `onSubmit={this.onSubmit}`. Thanks for your help!